# Holding git repository contents outside of git repository

Tags: git

Is it possible to map certain folders in a git repository to a different location outside of the repository folder? This should not affect any other users.
The problem is that the repo is really large and I'd like to store certain parts of it on a different disk.

I could fetch the offending folder, move it and then create a symlink or junction, but what if the folder is too big to put it in the initial location? Is there some kind of support in git to tell it that I want this folder on another location outside of the repository root?

Comment: like putting symlinks somewhere pointing to the contents of the git repo? the intended results of this question are very unclear.

Comment: `git worktree` plus `sparse checkout` can checkout certain files of a specific revision to a specific path outside the current repository.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much benefit in doing this as those folders probably won't be shared as well. Although I'm willing to be wrong here

Comment: I've expanded the question. Work tree would almost be like having two separate repos, I'd like to be able to see/commit/add/push all the changes with a single command/commit, regardless of the folder.

Comment: Git does not have such a feature. You can attempt to mount the secondary location in place of the directory in the working tree. Think bind mounts on Linux or junktion points on Windows.

Comment: You can separate [`.git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt) and [the worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---work-treeltpathgt) but you cannot split the worktree into different subfolders. It must be one single worktree.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the recent (Dec. 2020) post from [Derrick Stolee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127088/derrick-stolee): "[Get up to speed with partial clone and shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/), you can consider:

- cloning the all repository without any blob (so empty files: no space)

> `git clone --filter=blob:none <url>` creates a *blobless* clone.
> These clones download all reachable commits and trees while fetching blobs on-demand. These clones are best for developers and build environments that span multiple builds.

- cloning only part of your repository: "[Bring your monorepo down to size with sparse-checkout](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/) "

```sh
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout set <dir1> <dir2> ...
```

That way, you can clone only what you need.

Comment: I was aware of this, but the problem is that I need all of it, but don't have the space for ti on a single drive. And no, getting a bigger drive is not a solution in this case.